# Python script not writing to file when executed at boot

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to make a python loop script that will write to a file.

When I execute the script in terminal, the file gets written with no issue.

I wan't this script to start on boot, so I put it in the rc.local file. The script runs, however it is not writing the output to the specified file..

I did some reading on flushing and un-buffered output.. 
Could anyone help me out or point me in the right direction?

When this script is finished it will send the file using REST, but I need the file to write before I even get there..

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u

while True:
    try:
        print "This is only a test..."
        with open("loop.txt", "a") as loopFile:
            loopFile.write("This is only a test...")
            loopFile.write('\n')
            loopFile.flush()
            loopFile.close()
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
        quit()
```

The /etc/rc.local file:

```
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/loop.py &
```

loop.py and loop.txt both have read/write/execute access.

Comment: Since you use `with open()`, you don't need `loopFile.close()`

Comment: This script almost certainly runs in a different working directory than when you're on the terminal...you need to specify a full path name when opening the file.

Comment: This is because the file "loop.txt" don't exist when the OS runs it for you. You need to specify the full path

Comment: Add a full path to the file, for instance /tmp/loop.txt

Comment: Thanks everyone, I had a feeling it had to do with the file path, but I didn't know I had to specify in the open statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a full pathname to the statement opening the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u

while True:
    try:
        print "This is only a test..."
        with open("/home/users/sj091190/loop.txt", "a") as loopFile:
            loopFile.write("This is only a test...")
            loopFile.write('\n')
            loopFile.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
        quit()
```

Comment: thanks @martineau ! I've never asked a question so I was unsure of the etiquette